# How to place a slider over on top of a videobrush

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am attempting to create a slider control which will determine the scaletransform of a videobrush in my MainPage, and was wondering if it was possible to somehow place this slider on top of the videobrush (which I would like to be full screen)? Currently I am using a grid for my layout where a videobrush takes up the whole screen except for two buttons on the bottom of the screen, but I would like to possibly use a canvas and place this slider in a way that would account for the current and future screen sizes of a Windows Phone device. I am unsure of how to exactly accomplish this without setting constant dimensions for the slider. For instance the slider may be placed horizontally near the bottom of the screen in Portrait mode and would have a 50 pixel space between the left and right sides. Could someone assist with how this could be done?

EDIT

Placing a single child element over the videobrush works, although I would like to place more than one slider which gives an error. I also wanted to add information above and below each slider so I chose a stackpanel to do this (yet only one stackpanel as a child element is allowed?).

```
<Border x:Name="videoRectangle" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
            <Border.Background>
                <VideoBrush  x:Name="viewfinderBrush">
                    <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="viewfinderBrushTransform" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" Rotation="90" />
                    </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </VideoBrush>
            </Border.Background>

            <!--<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock x:Name="resolutionValueTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=resolutionSlider}"/>
                <Slider x:Name="resolutionSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="50,5,50,5"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="resolutionTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="resolution"/>
            </StackPanel>-->

            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock x:Name="zoomNumberTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=zoomSlider}"/>
                <Slider x:Name="zoomSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="50,5,50,5"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="zoomTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="zoom"/>
            </StackPanel>

</Border>
```

If possible I would like both stackpanels to be available, but if not I guess I would have to use the bottom one only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stay with the Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VideoBrush ... />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="50,5,50,5"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is it possible to set more than one child element over the videobrush? I would actually like to implement two slider controls with textblocks above and below each indicating the number value of the slider and the name of the slider, one on the top of the page and one on the bottom of the page but I am getting the error `The property 'Child' is set more than once.` I edited my original post to reflect this for reference. If this is not possible, would you recommend another way this might be accomplished?

Comment: The reason for the error in your original post code with two sliders, is that Border elements can only have one child. Use the grid, as Clemens suggested, since Grid elements can have multiple children. If you need the properties that the Border provides, use a Grid within a Border element.